# ArangoDB REST API: Unable to set user password

Tags: rest, authentication, arangodb, nosql

I am able to create a user using by following what the doc says:

```
curl -X POST --user root:root --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/user <<EOF
{ 
  "user" : "testUser", 
  "password" : "secure" 
}
EOF
```

But the password argument seems to be ignored by Arango.

```
curl -v --user testUser:secure http://localhost:8529/_api/user/testUser
```

Returns a 401

While:

```
curl -v --user testUser: http://localhost:8529/_api/user/testUser
```

Returns a 200

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to excuse our documentation team - You obviously copied the CURL example from

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/users/

which has a typo in the post bodies of the examples (added during the 3.0 release cycle). As the body parameter parameter description proberly names it, the password is specified via the `passwd` key instead of the `password` key.

The error is corrected and an updated version of the documentation will be online soon.

Thanks for taking the time to dig deeper.